# React- FLUX - Pass Object as Param - Undefined

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs

I have a simple react app, I get a list of contacts from a web api and i want to display them. Each contact has a name, last name, phone etc
My app class gets the contacts then renders as

```
render(){
var contact= this.state.contacts[0];
 return( <div><Contact label='First Contact' person={contact}/></div>
)
}
```

Then in my Contact class

```
render(){
return(
<div> {this.props.label} : {this.props.person.Name}</div>)
}
```

When I debug on chrome, I see that person is passed as prop, object has all the parameters, however when I run the code, on the {this.props.person.Name} I get error

```
Cannot read property Name of undefined
```

If I remove that, {this.props.label} is displayed without issue. So I can pass text as prop but not the object. 
Any idea?

- Edit: I can also pass the Name property as
  Contact personName= {contact.Name}/>
  This works but not passing the contact as object and then reading properties in the render of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is (since you're using flux) that upon loading the page (initial load) the contacts on your state represents an empty array.

Try

```
var contact= this.state.contacts[0] || {};
```

and for some good tips => don't use vars, use const :-)

let your component listen to your flux store:

Make sure your flux store holds an addChangeListener and removeChangeListener function that you can call in your component so your component gets updated automatically

```
componentDidMount(){
  myStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  myStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
}

_onChange = () => {
  this.setState({contacts: myStore.getContacts()});
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have the code bit you mentioned, but state in parent level is not null, I can do alert(this.state.documents.length)

Comment: I just followed ' for some good tips => don't use vars, use const :-)' 
And it worked! apparently if I define the object as var and pass as prop, I cant go to properties of Json object in the child component but if I define the object as const, no problem.  Thanks